# ORA-01841 Error when aplying conditions on date in where clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, where-clause, to-date, sysdate

I need to pick the data of expired credit cards for customers.
As you know, the expiration date of a card only uses month in MM format and year in YY format. In my database all of the expiration dates are stored in MMYY format, so I use TO_DATE(FONDOS.VENCTARJETA, 'MMYY') to get a date and then to apply some conditions.

This is my Query:

```
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(FONDOS.VENCTARJETA, 'MMYY') AS F_VENCIMIENTO
FROM 
    POLIZA POLIZA,
    DATOS_FONDOSPOL FONDOS
WHERE
    POLIZA.IDEPOL = FONDOS.IDEPOL AND
    --TO_DATE(FONDOS.VENCTARJETA, 'MMYY') <= SYSDATE AND
    POLIZA.CODINTER = TO_NUMBER(:P2_CLAVE)
```

This is returning 89 rows like these:

```
F_VENCIMIENTO      |
-------------------|
                   |
2023-08-01 00:00:00|
2020-08-01 00:00:00|
2021-11-01 00:00:00|
2020-09-01 00:00:00|
                   |
2023-02-01 00:00:00|
---- many more ----
```

With the results, we notice there are no errors when converting 'MMYY' date into a date type column.

As you can see, I commented a condition in where clause, then if I uncomment the line I get this:

> ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

This is not the only behaviour where I am getting this error, but this was the simplest I got to show you how it fails.

It has no logic, I can't find why it happens.
Please, help.
Thanks.

Comment: What type is `F_VENCIMIENTO`?

Comment: Besides your question (for which you already have two good answers), please consider these two additional potential logical mistakes in the approach. First, if for some reason you still have cards that expired in 1998 (for example), they may have an expiration date of '1098'. You should use the `'RR'` format model for year, rather than `'YY'`, if that kind of expiration date is possible in your data. And, separately, a card with expiration of 0920 does not expire on 1 SEPT 2020 - it expires on 1 OCT 2020. You need this one-month adjustment in your WHERE condition. Use the ADD_MONTHS function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter conditions can be executed in any order Oracle decides is best. It suggests that you have some rows in your table that do not properly convert to a date using that particular format mask, but do get filtered out by your join condition. When you include the filter, Oracle probably sees that it can prefilter on your `datos_fondospol` table before joining to your other table, at which point every row will hit the function.

If you are on at least Oracle version 12.2 you can identify all the rows that contain data that can't be converted to a date with that format mask with `validate_conversion`:

```
select 
from   datos_fondospol 
where  validate_conversion(venctarjeta as date, 'MMYY') = 0
```

If this data is correct but can safely be ignored then you can use another 12.2 addition:

```
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(FONDOS.VENCTARJETA, 'MMYY') AS F_VENCIMIENTO
FROM 
    POLIZA POLIZA,
    DATOS_FONDOSPOL FONDOS
WHERE
    POLIZA.IDEPOL = FONDOS.IDEPOL AND
    TO_DATE(FONDOS.VENCTARJETA default null on conversion error, 'MMYY') <= SYSDATE AND
    POLIZA.CODINTER = TO_NUMBER(:P2_CLAVE)
```

If you are only on 12.1 then you can make a similar function yourself with a `with plsql` clause:

```
with 
 function default_date(dateString varchar2,dateFormat varchar2)
 return date
 is
   convertedDate  date;
 begin
   convertedDate := to_date(dateString,dateFormat );
   return convertedDate ;
 exception when others then
   return null;
 end;
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(FONDOS.VENCTARJETA, 'MMYY') AS F_VENCIMIENTO
FROM 
    POLIZA POLIZA,
    DATOS_FONDOSPOL FONDOS
WHERE
    POLIZA.IDEPOL = FONDOS.IDEPOL AND
    default_date(FONDOS.VENCTARJETA, 'MMYY') <= SYSDATE AND
    POLIZA.CODINTER = TO_NUMBER(:P2_CLAVE)
```

If you are on less than that then you can make the PL/SQL function explicitly and call it. Or you could manufacture a `case` expression to check the contents of your string first.

```
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(FONDOS.VENCTARJETA, 'MMYY') AS F_VENCIMIENTO
FROM 
    POLIZA POLIZA,
    DATOS_FONDOSPOL FONDOS
WHERE
    POLIZA.IDEPOL = FONDOS.IDEPOL AND
    case when regexp_like (FONDOS.VENCTARJETA, '^[0-9]{4}$')
 and to_number(substr(FONDOS.VENCTARJETA,1,2)) between 1 and 12  
 then to_date(FONDOS.VENCTARJETA, 'MMYY') else cast(null as date) end <= SYSDATE AND
    POLIZA.CODINTER = TO_NUMBER(:P2_CLAVE)
```

Comment: This makes sense, with one exception (I think). The OP stated a very specific error that is thrown, having to do with the year having to be within bounds and not zero. I can't think of any (invalid) string that will throw that precise error, when used in `to_date` with the format model `'MMYY'`. What might that be?

Comment: You can get that error if you have letters where the year number should be:
`select to_date('01AA','MMYY') from dual;` gives this error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ff72ad80d5cebe2c8de5750cfd19872 .

Comment: Oh! You are right - I was able to replicate. Interesting of choice (specific error to throw in that case).

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewSayer, that validate_conversion function helped me a lot, I didn't know it.
There were two rows with data format different from MMYY, were in MM/YY format.

I changed `TO_DATE(FONDOS.VENCTARJETA, 'MMYY')` to `TO_DATE(FONDOS.VENCTARJETA, 'MM/YY')` and it seems to work with both 'MM/YY' and 'MMYY' formats.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one row in the `VENCTARJETA` column in `DATOS_FONDOSPOL` where the string cannot be converted to a valid date.  If you look at the query plan with and without the commented condition, my guess is that when the condition is present, Oracle applies the `sysdate` predicate before the `CODINTER` predicate and/ or before the join filters out the row with invalid data.  If your plan happens to filter out the bad data before applying the `to_date` function, the query will seem to work.  But if something causes the plan to change and the `to_date` function gets applied before the bad data is filtered out, you'll get an error.

Answer (score -1):

Have tried with a use case not sure if this is what you are looking for

--- Table creation with sample data--------------

CREATE TABLE POLIZA(IDPOL number, VENCTARJETA DATE);

CREATE TABLE DATOS_FONDOSPOL(IDPOL number, X_EXTRA varchar2(10));

INSERT INTO POLIZA VALUES (2001,to_date('0816','MM/YY'));
INSERT INTO POLIZA VALUES (2002,to_date('1016','MM/YY'));

INSERT INTO DATOS_FONDOSPOL values(2002 , 'zzzz');
INSERT INTO DATOS_FONDOSPOL values(2001 , 'zzzz');

---

### The select below works for me fine, all i did  is used TO_CHAR

```
SELECT 
   TO_CHAR(POLIZA.VENCTARJETA, 'MMYY')AS F_VENCIMIENTO
FROM 
    POLZIA POLIZA,
    DATOS_FONDOSPOL FONDOS
WHERE
    POLIZA.IDPOL = FONDOS.IDPOL 
    AND TO_CHAR(POLIZA.VENCTARJETA, 'MMYY') <= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-120, 'MMYY');
```